# Searching two patterns in files that appear in the same file but may not appear on the same line

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

From a directory, I need to find all files that contain a decimal numbers say 42.7 AND the keyword "foo" or "goo". How could I achieve that?

Suppose I have a directory with three files

```
file1.txt
=======
double x = 2.7
foo();

file2.txt
===========
double u = 5.7

file3.txt
===========
goo(42.0);
```

The search command should give file1.txt and file3.txt. What is a search command to achieve this?

i searched for the solutions but all I could find deal with having the patterns simultaneously appearing in the same line.  Also I got difficulty in dealing with the decimal dot.

Comment: I don't see `42.7` anywhere, how are any of the files matching it?

Comment: Re "decimal dot" -- have you tried escaping it? (in both bash and regex? -- this should already be answered somewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 `grep -l` commands to list the file names (not the matched lines) that contain the regex. Connect them by `xargs`, for example like so:

```
grep -Pl '(\d+[.]?\d*|\d*[.]?\d+)' file?.txt | xargs grep -Pl '(foo|goo)'
```

Example:

Create the input files. I use a few more examples in addition to the ones listed in the question to illustrate the patterns/files that are found:

```
cat > file1.txt <<EOF
double x = 2.7
foo();
EOF

cat > file2.txt <<EOF
double u = 5.7
EOF

cat > file3.txt <<EOF
goo(42.0);
EOF

cat > file4.txt <<EOF
foo(4);
EOF

cat > file5.txt <<EOF
goo(.42);
EOF

cat > file6.txt <<EOF
goo(.);
EOF
```

Run `grep -l ... | xargs grep -l ...` to find the matching files:

```
grep -Pl '(\d+[.]?\d*|\d*[.]?\d+)' file?.txt | xargs grep -Pl '(foo|goo)'
```

Prints:

```
file1.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-l` : list the file names only, not the matching lines.

The regex has the following parts:
`\d*` : any digit 0-9, repeated 0 or more times.
`\d+` : same, repeated 1 or more times.
`[.]` : literal dot (`.`). Otherwise, without escaping, `.` means any character.

**SEE ALSO:**

> `-l`
> `--files-with-matches`
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from
> which output would normally have been printed. The scanning of each
> file stops on the first match. (`-l` is specified by POSIX.)

[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Comment: Thanks. Why use Perl regex? Is it a standard?

Comment: @zell Perl regex is not standard, but it is an option with GNU grep. I like it because it is often easier to write and maintain. But you can rewrite this using standard regex if you like.